# Can I avoid the lost in quality of pixel graphics in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, png, rendering

Im making a videogame in flash (using AS3, Flash CS6, flashDevelop, etc) and almost all the big code is done. So I made some new graphics in photoshop, exported as PNG, loaded them to the library and replaced some of the placeholder vector art. When I tested the movie I noticed a huge drop in quality even when the code does no scaling at all.

http://i.imgur.com/qIE7Vk9.jpg

Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: What in particular? Game is pretty big by now. I didnt think there was anything really relevant that I could post. Maybe its againts the rules (if so let me know and i'll delete the thread) but i was asking a more broad question about pixelar graphics and how to implement them in a flash player/AS3 project.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i feel kinda silly answering this like 5 minutes after posting the question but you can set the properties for the file inside the library so it isnt compressed any further.

http://i.imgur.com/iI2mnLa.jpg